# How much do the live-action Nana films cover?

Tags: nana

I've seen bits and pieces of the *Nana* films before, and I'm thinking of watching them again for the nostalgia kick. I am aware that there is also an anime adaptation of the manga, which I assume does not cover the entirety of the manga. (The anime ran in 2006, and the manga last published in 2009.)

I've been recommended the anime before (albeit by a friend who had somewhat different taste in this sort of thing), so on the off-chance I end up wanting to watch the anime or read the manga after seeing the film: **how much of the manga do the live-action films cover? Are there any major changes to plot or characters that I should be aware of?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The live action goes up to episode 19 of the anime series, which in turn is shorter than the manga (only goes up to the 12th volume out of 21).

There's a lot of plot and relationship changes that happen in the future chapters, rather than spoil them here you should read to find out :D

Unfortunately, the manga does not have a conclusion just yet as it was put on hiatus in June 2009 when Yazawa became ill. So just be aware that there is a lot of loose ends in the *current* final chapters